# Accessing Rails 4.2.3 with Ruby 1.9.3 gives Byebug error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been trying to use Ruby 1.9.3 and set up Rails since I've been having an error deploying `rails` when using Ruby versions >= 2.0.

Now, I've been running `bundle install` in the CMD and it gives me this error:

```
Gem::InstallError: byebug requires Ruby version >= 2.0.0.
An error occurred while installing byebug (5.0.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that 'gem install byebug -v '5.0.0'' succeeds before bundling.
```

I've manually installed it and it doesn't work as well. So I've been typing rails commands including `rails -v` and I've been getting an error that they could not find byebug.

How do I work around this problem since I'm using Ruby 1.9.3? Is there any way for me to make Ruby versions >= 2 work in Windows 8?

Answer (score 2):

Since `byebug` originally supports `v2.0.0` up by default

You can use older version of debugger tool for rails which is `debugger`

`gem install debugger` should suffice.

Comment: Removing `byebug` from gemfile and re-`bundle install` is needed as well.

Comment: Hey guys! I have tried installing debugger and re-bundle install, it still requires ByeBug for some reason. And I couldn't remove byebug from the gemfile since it's not installed in the first place. What do you suggest?

Comment: Did you remove `byebug` in Gemfile and delete `Gemfile.lock`?